# URLstring class for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am using the NSURL class in the iPhone framework foundation library to create a url request to a server. For some reason, I am getting back a nil for only this particular URL.
I don't understand why. Any reason?

The Objective C code is :

NSURL *scriptURL= [NSURL URLWithString:scriptURLString];

where scriptURLString is an NSString with value give below:

http://myserver/cgi-bin/AdsERsubset.cgi?user=139&fieldList=employee_num,mbox_num,last_name,first_name,disp_emp_num,company_num,TECH_PRIVILEDGE,printer_code,desktop_cos,id,supv_emp_num&action=first&searchkey=1 with proxy=DIRECT

The above URL is a CGI request.

Is there a special character I need to escape here?

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spaces in the searchkey should be escaped.

Use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` on the url string before passing it to URLWithString:

```
NSURL *scriptURL= [NSURL URLWithString:[scriptURLString 
          stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: I have a custom class and an NSString field in that class. I have created an object and am trying to assign a value to the NSString field but the code is breaking. I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Here is the sample:        tech.employee_num = [[NSString alloc] stringWithString:(NSString *)[[[EmployeeArray objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]];

Comment: You should ask that as a new question with more information including what you mean by "the code is breaking".

Answer (score 0):

> ...&searchkey=1 with proxy=DIRECT

Your missing an & aren't you?

I'd imagine it would be more like:

> ...&searchkey=1&with%20proxy=DIRECT

or

> ...&searchkey=1&withproxy=DIRECT

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The logic on the first reply solved it for me.